# Is it possible to use \only to conditionally enable key-value pairs of a macro?

Tags: beamer, pstricks

The following is a trivial example. What I want to learn is how to use `\only<>` (if possible) to conditionally enable key-value pairs of a macro.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=12pt\relax

\makeatletter
\let\Test@pr@shipout\pr@shipout%% save the original definition
\let\Test@shipout\shipout
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\pr@shipout\Test@pr@shipout%% restore it 
  \let\shipout\Test@shipout
}
\makeatother


\def\RightPart{
    % start from ear to tail
    \only<+->{\moveto(.5,2.7)}
    \only<+->{\psline(1,3.25)}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(1.2,1.3)(1.3,1)(2,1)}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(3,1)(3,2.2)(!3.3 6 72 p2c)}
    \only<+->{\psellipticarcn(6,3.3){(!3.3 6 72 p2c)}{(!3.3 6 72 neg p2c)}}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(4,-2)(4,0)(2.2,-1.8)}
    \only<+->{\psbezier(1.5,-1)(1,-1)(0,-3.2)}
}

\def\LeftPart{
    % start from tail to ear
        \only<+->{\psbezier(1,-1)(1.5,-1)(2.2,-1.8)}
        \only<+->{\psbezier(4,0)(4,-2)(!3.3 6 72 neg p2c)}
        \only<+->{\psellipticarc(6,3.3){(!3.3 6 72 neg p2c)}{(!3.3 6 72 p2c)}}  
        \only<+->{\psbezier(3,2.2)(3,1)(2,1)}    
        \only<+->{\psbezier(1.3,1)(1.2,1.3)(1,3.25)}
        \only<+->{\psline(.5,2.7)}      
        \only<+->{\closepath}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-6,-3)(6,3)  
    \pstVerb{/p2c {dup 3 1 roll cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul} bind def}
    %\pscustom[\only<15->{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow}]
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow]
    {
        \RightPart
        \code{-1 1 scale}
        \LeftPart
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So how can I use `\pscustom[\only<15->{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow}]` to let me fill the closed region at the last? Please don't suggest me to use `psclip` because it is not what I want to learn.

Comment: I don't use pstricks but in tikz, I think you could draw the path at one point and then fill it later using an overlay specification. There is a question about incrementally uncovering graphics created with tikz in beamer somewhere so you might look for that and try to do something analogous in pstricks.

Comment: @cfr: So it is not possible,right?

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible. I just said one way I thought it could be done with tikz in case you wanted to adapt that method to pstricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving the `fillstyle` option directly to `\pscustom` you can use `\fill[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=yellow]` which can be wrapped with `\only`. So the relevant change in your code is:

```
\pscustom{
    \RightPart
    \code{-1 1 scale}
    \LeftPart
    \only<+->{\fill[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=yellow]}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Because it is put at the end so `\only<+->` is much better than `\only<15>`.